# Fetch MYSQL row by id and edit and update in form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function

I have a MYSQL table with edit link and delete button on each row. The edit link goes to edit_movie.php which has a form. My problem is that the form is not showing any data to be updated/edited. How do I fetch the id from the row clicked on or what function to write to pick it up. The form is just blank, no fields are filled out.

Could someone help out I´d be very happy! Been sitting with this problem for 3 days now and just can´t get it to work. I'm a PHP beginner...

I know I'm using mysql functions which are outdated and I need to lookover SQL injection which I will once I get this working.

**Table info:**

Table 1 name: Movies
Fields: id (primary key, AI), title, release_year, genre_id, director

Table 2 name: Categories
Fields: genre_id (primary key, AI), genre

They have a foreign relation between genre_id.

**Here is the code in index.php file**

```
    <?php

require('movie.inc.php');

if ( isset($_GET['delete']) && isset($_GET['id']) ){
   if ( delete_movie_by_id($_GET['id']) ){ //it's 100% safe
       die('Movie has been removed. Refresh the page now'); // or the like
   } else {
      echo 'Sorry movie could not be deleted'; // could not - handle here
   }
}
    include 'add_movie.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>My movie library</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mall.css" />

</head>
<body>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Release year</th>
  <th>Genre</th><th>Director</th>
  <th>Update</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
 </tr>

  <?php  foreach (get_all_movies() as $index => $row) : ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['release_year']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['genre'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['director'];?></td>
     <td><a href='<?php printf('edit_movie.php?edit=%s', $row['id']);?>'>Edit</a></td>
     <td>
      <form action="index.php" method="GET">
              <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" /> 
              <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
      </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the edit_movie.php code:**

```
 <?php

    require 'connect.inc.php';
    require_once('movie.inc.php');

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>

    <title>My movie library</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mall.css" />

    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>Edit movie</h1>
    <div id="form_column">
    <form action="edit_movie.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if (isset($row["id"])) ?>" /> <br>
    Title:<br> <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if (isset($row["title"])) { echo $row["title"];} ?>" /> <br>
    Release Year:<br> <input type="text" name="release_year" value="<?php if (isset($row["release_year"])) { echo $row["release_year"];} ?>" /> <br>
    Director:<br> <input type="text" name="director" value="<?php if (isset($row["director"])) { echo $row["director"];} ?>" /> <br><br>
    Select genre:
    <br>
    <br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="1" checked />Action<br>
    <br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="2" />Comedy<br>
    <br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="3" />Drama<br>
    <br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="4" />Horror<br>
    <br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="5" />Romance<br>
    <br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="6" />Thriller<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Update movie" />
    </form>
    </div>



    </body>

    </html>
```

**And here is the movie.inc.php file**

```
<?php

require_once('connect.inc.php');


function get_all_movies(){

   $query = "SELECT * FROM movies m INNER JOIN categories c ON m.genre_id = c.genre_id";

   $result = mysql_query($query);

   if ( ! $result ){ 
     return false;
   } else {
     $return = array();

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $return[] = array('director' => $row['director'], 'genre' => $row['genre'], 'release_year' => $row['release_year'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'id' => $row['id']); 
     }
       return $return;
   }
}


function delete_movie_by_id($id){
   return mysql_unbuffered_query(sprintf("DELETE FROM `movies` WHERE id='%s' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($id)));
}

if ( isset($_POST['delete'], $_POST['id']) ){

   delete_movie_by_id($_POST['id']); 
}


?>
```

Comment: Omg, After 4 years this question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `edit_movie.php` it doesn't look like you're actually getting the movie passed view the form. You need something like this in your `movie.inc.php`:

```
function get_movie_to_edit($id) {

     $query = "SELECT * FROM movies m INNER JOIN categories c ON m.genre_id = c.genre_id WHERE id = $id";

     $result = mysql_query($query);

     if ( ! $result ){ 
         return false;
     } else {

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $return = array('director' => $row['director'], 'genre' => $row['genre'], 'release_year' => $row['release_year'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'id' => $row['id']); 
         }
             return $return;
     }
}
```

And then in edit_movie.php you need to call this function. Something like...

```
if(isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $movie = get_movie_to_edit($_GET['edit']);
}
```

Of course, as you mentioned, you need to clean up a lot of the code to prevent against injection and check for a scenario where, say, you get to `edit_movie.php` and the ID ro edit doesn't exist, but this is the basic gist.

You would also then edit the values in the form in `edit_movie.php` to reflect the new array like:

```
<form action="edit_movie.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $movie['id']; ?>" /> <br>
Title:<br> <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $movie['title']; ?>" /> <br>
.... the rest of your form inputs
</form>
```

**Updated**
For the genre radio buttons...

```
<input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="1"<?php if($movie['genre'] == 1) { echo ' checked'; } ?> />Action<br>
<input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="2"<?php if($movie['genre'] == 2) { echo ' checked'; } ?> />Comedy<br>
.... and so on
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment! So I just tried your code, I think it´s almost the same as I tried before and I get the same error in all the form fields: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: title in <b>C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\test\edit_movie.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />   Do you know what to do? How can I define the 'title' etc..

Comment: See my edit. When you build the $return array, make it like: `$return = ...` instead of `$return[] = ...`

Comment: Oh jeez!!! It´s working!!! Only thing though. In edit_movie.php how should I write the value for the radio buttons? On title etc its value="<?php echo $movie['id']; but on the radion buttons the value is already set on the genre_id. So it doesn´t work there...

Comment: no I´m still trying to the the radio buttons to work:( With the code you wote I had an error undefined end of file or something like that, now I´m just trying to change different commas etc but it´s not working...

Comment: Should there be a closing } efter each echo maybe?

Comment: Yes. I just updated my code above. Adding code in these comments is not the best place. I'm delete my first comment so this doesn't confuse people later.

Comment: At this point you need to provide more information like what error(s) are you getting? Also, are your genres in the DB stored as numbers? I'm only assuming that from your orignal post. If they are not, then you need something like: `if($movie['genre'] == 'Action')` or whatever you genres actually are.

I would say your question is answered and you have enough to figure out the rest with some experimentation.

Comment: I double checked so correct values are filled out etc. None of the radio buttons are filled out now so just empty... No error message.. I could start a new thread though for this! As you did help me out with the bigger picture here! SUPER THANKS for that as I´ve been working with this issue for 3 days!